# I am designing a table in angularjs with multi text filtering option for each column like in excel

Tags: javascript, angularjs, excel

I am designing a table in AngularJS with many rows and columns. I need to add a filter button ![filter button][1]for each of the columns. When clicking on the  filter button it should expand to something like in exce, which lists all the elements in the column and pick the necessary data to filter. Is there a way to do this in AngularJS? Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Lets use this sheet as an example

```
A B C
2|4|1
3|2|2
 | |3
7| |4
 | |2
 | |3
 | |2
```

Lets build the internals of the spreadsheet in javascript. You can move the columns object to a json file to read in for persistence.

```
var sheet = {
    columns = [
        [2, 3, null, 7], // A 
        [4, 2], // B
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 2] // C
    ],
    maxRowCount: function () {
        var max = 0;
        columns.forEach(function (item) {
            max = Math.max(max, item.length);
        });  
        return max;
    }
};

function filterHandler(filterOptions, colIndex) {
    // pass in an array of the values you want to show
    var rowsToShow = [];
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < sheet.maxRowCount(); i++) {
        if (sheet.columns[colIndex] in filterOptions) {
            rowsToShow.push(i + 1); // for one based rows.
        }
    }
    return rowsToShow;
}
```

From here you need to do some stuff with the dom. Use something like a list of check boxes to mark what items you want to filter for. pass it into the filterHandler. It will return an array of indices to show. Hide all others.

To filter Column C on values 2 and 4 do the following

```
var showRows = filterHandler([2, 4], 2);
// showRows == [2, 4, 5, 7]
```

So hide all rows who's indicies are not in the showRows array.

Comment: thank you so much for helping me out with this. I am new angularjs is there a live demo I could use to learn the way it is done. It would be so helpful if there was a plunkr version to this code.